# Pandas_datareader: ticker data type of get_nasdaq_symbols()

Tags: stocks, nasdaq

I used `pandas_datarader` for getting stock data of NASDAQ.

I found out `get_nasdaq_symbols()` and it returns some good information for each stock.

Here is the code:

```
In [27]: from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
    ...:
    ...: all_symbols = pdr.get_nasdaq_symbols()
    ...:
    ...: all_symbols.head()
    ...:
Out[27]:
        Nasdaq Traded                                      Security Name  \
Symbol
A                True            Agilent Technologies, Inc. Common Stock
AA               True                    Alcoa Corporation Common Stock
AAAP             True  Advanced Accelerator Applications S.A. - Ameri...
AABA             True                         Altaba Inc. - Common Stock
AAC              True                    AAC Holdings, Inc. Common Stock

       Listing Exchange Market Category    ETF  Round Lot Size  Test Issue  \
Symbol
A                     N                  False           100.0       False
AA                    N                  False           100.0       False
AAAP                  Q               Q  False           100.0       False
AABA                  Q               Q  False           100.0       False
AAC                   N                  False           100.0       False

       Financial Status CQS Symbol NASDAQ Symbol  NextShares
Symbol
A                   NaN          A             A       False
AA                  NaN         AA            AA       False
AAAP                  N        NaN          AAAP       False
AABA                  N        NaN          AABA       False
AAC                 NaN        AAC           AAC       False
```

It returns `pandas DataFrame` object. Now I picked one row(symbol)

```
In [28]: all_symbols.loc['AAPL']
Out[28]:
Nasdaq Traded                            True
Security Name       Apple Inc. - Common Stock
Listing Exchange                            Q
Market Category                             Q
ETF                                     False
Round Lot Size                            100
Test Issue                              False
Financial Status                            N
CQS Symbol                                NaN
NASDAQ Symbol                            AAPL
NextShares                              False
Name: AAPL, dtype: object
```

I'd like to know what the meaning of each column indicates. I have looked source code but it doesn't have any information about that.

Specifically, below is what I am curious about:

1. `Listing Exchange`: meaning of itself and what values(`'A', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'Z', None`) of it indicate
2. `Market Category` : meaning of `' ', 'G', 'Q', 'S'` (its value set)
3. `Test Issue` : which test does it indicate?
4. `Financial Status` : meaning of `nan, 'D', 'H', 'N', 'G', 'E'` (its value set)
5. `CQS symbol`: what does `CQS` means in detail?
6. `NextShares`: what does `NextShares` means?

Thanks

Comment: http://nasdaqtrader.com/content/technicalSupport/specifications/dataproducts/dlcompletespec.pdf should be the correct documentation from NASDAQ for the API; it appears to contain everything that you need to know.